# Visual studio code "files.exclude" not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

Yesterday I added files.exclude to my user settings in visual studio code to hide .js and .map files and it worked correctly. But today (and without restarting or closing code) it stopped working.

This is the full settings.json file

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "app/*.js": true,
        "app/*.map": true
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: can you add your project structure? are you seeing map files in app folder also or the map files inside some deep folder?

Comment: it is the angular 2 tutorial, I think the only map files are in that folder... I can see the js files in the node_modules folder

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding "**/" before each exclude, I might have opened the project in a different way and didn't notice the parent folder had been added to the project structure

Comment: You might want `app/**/*.js` which means all .js files under the `app` folder (recursive). `**/app/*.js` means all .js files any folder named `app`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already got the answer but thought of posting as this might be a solution for others. Below worked for me.

```
"**/app/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"} or

"**/app/**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running VSCode 1.47.3 (in 2020) and this works well for typescript.

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }
}
```